# Rails 3 rateable model - How to create ajax rating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I create some simple ajax rating like there is on this page http://watir.com/documentation/ ? Every visitor should be able to rate, I dont need to set permissions. I want to store the ratings in a column. So the user can sort by ratings. 
Please make an detailled example. I am not a javascript expert.

I have found an example to create ratings from scratch. But it authorizes a user.
Can someone show me a guidance to create ratings without a Rater (user)? It should not only store the values but also count the votes.

http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3

Comment: https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating

Comment: I have found a guide to create ratings from scratch. But all users should be able to rate. http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did recently to add a simple rating mechanism to an existing project was the following:

I added two fields to an existing table (which contained the items to be rated). Those were:

```
rating_score => The current score
ratings => The number of ratings which led to the score
```

For example, if five users would've voted "5" for the current item, `rating_score` would be 25, and ratings would be 5. The current rating would be computed as `rating_score / ratings`.

Then I added a new method to the controller of the items to be rated, called "rate", which looked something like:

```
def rate
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @container = "item"+@item.id.to_s

    @item.rating_score += params[:rating].to_i
    @item.ratings += 1
    @item.save

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

My view for that method, called `rate.js.erb`, would look something like

```
$('#<%= @container %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'rating', locals: { item: @item })) %>');
```

This code works only if you've got jQuery installed, but it should be easily translatable to Prototype or whatever JS framework you may be using.

And the [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for the rating, called `_rating.html.erb`, was something like:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'items',  action: 'rate', id: item.id), remote: true %>
    <%= rating_stars(item.rating_score, item.ratings) %>
    <%= item.ratings %> Votes
</form>
```

In this partial, the `rating_stars()` helper method generated some kind of star-like representation for the rating, but you can do that however you like.

By setting "remote: true" in the form_tag helper, your Rails installation should automatically transmit the request via the installed Javascript framework. This magic is part of the whole [unobtrusive javascript](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) thing going on in Rails lately, which is actually pretty cool.

Hope this gives you an idea of how to realize a very simple rating system **with no IP lock feature whatsoever** in Rails.

Comment: would you mind posting the rating star helper please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Watir documentation rating system is set up through [polldaddy](http://polldaddy.com/features/#ratings).

For this particular case, it appears they include the polldaddy javascript which populates the rating div container with their star rating widget. Looks like there's a corresponding javascript object which you can inspect:

```
console.log( PDRTJS_101132_page_2.avg_rating ); //=> 4
```

If you had numerous rating widgets like these on a page, and you were able to make a collection of the javascript objects paired with their divs, presumably you could sort them based on that average rating property.