# Rails ajax rating help how to create a helper method to display stars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating, some simple Ajax rating. Based on the first answer on this question [Rails 3 rateable model - How to create ajax rating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033879/rails-3-rateable-model-how-to-create-ajax-rating)

And the partial for the rating, called `_rating.html.erb`, was something like:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'items', action: 'rate', id: item.id), remote: true %>
    <%= rating_stars(item.rating_score, item.ratings) %>
    <%= item.ratings %> Votes </form>
```

In this partial, the `rating_stars()`
helper method generated some kind of
star-like representation for the
rating, but you can do that however
you like.

How do I create the `rating_stars` helper method to display the stars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at using the **[jQuery RateIt plugin](http://rateit.codeplex.com/)**.

It is entirely client side JavaScript and CSS. It also sports some sweet unobtrusive JavaScript and progressive enhancement. I've been pleased with it in my projects.

Once you've included jquery.rateit.min.js, rateit.css, delete.gif and star.gif into your public directories, you might have something like the following inside your rails form:

```
<%= f.text_field :ratings, :size => 1, :min => 0, :max => 5, :step => 1 %>
<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#item_ratings" data-rateit-resetable="true">
</div>
```

The ID in `data-rateit-backingfld` should match the ID produced by the `text_field` form helper for your items field.

Clearly, this is using HTML5 data attributes, but if you're using Rails 3, then you'll be using HTML5 by default.

Comment: There's a lot of information in the examples link which is linked from the page in my answer, but I've revised my answer for you with a code snippet.

Comment: Can you help my with my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523557/rails-help-ajax-rating

Comment: As author of the RateIt plugin, I want to thank you for your nice words!