# Rails help creating ajax star rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a bit trouble creating some simple ajax rating based on these two answers. [Rails 3 rateable model - How to create ajax rating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033879/rails-3-rateable-model-how-to-create-ajax-rating) and [Rails ajax rating help how to create a helper method to display stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516970/rails-ajax-rating-help-how-to-create-a-helper-method-to-display-stars)

I get the following error in my kategori view:

```
NameError in Kategoris#show

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/kategoris/_rating.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x3c77820>:0x3c724f8>

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'konkurrancers',  action: 'rate', id: "#{vind.id}"), remote: true %>
2: <%= f.text_field :ratings, :size => 1, :min => 0, :max => 5, :step => 1 %>
3: <div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#konkurrancer_ratings" data-rateit-resetable="true">
4: </div>
5: </form>
```

My kategori show view:

```
<h1><%= @kategori.h2.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></h1>
<div id="konkurrancer"><%= render 'konkurrencer', :remote => true %></div>
</div>
```

My konkurrencer partial:

```
<div id="tabel">
<table id="tabel1" border="0" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="725" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr id="toptr">
      <td><%= sortable "name", "Navn" %></td>
   </tr>
<% @konkurrancer.each do |vind| %>
   <tr class="thumbnail-item" onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#99ff33';this.style.cursor='pointer'">
      <td width="280px" style="padding-left: 5px;"><%= truncate(vind.name.force_encoding("UTF-8"), :length => 45) %></td>

<td><div id="container"><%= render :partial => "rating", :remote => true, :locals => { :vind => vind } %></div></td>

</div>
   </tr> <% end %>
</table>
<div id="pagenavi">
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
</div>
```

My ratings partial:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'konkurrancers',  action: 'rate', id: "#{vind.id}"), remote: true %>
<%= f.text_field :ratings, :size => 1, :min => 0, :max => 5, :step => 1 %>
<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#konkurrancer_ratings" data-rateit-resetable="true">
</div>
</form>
```

My rate.js:

```
$('#<%= @container %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'rating', locals: { konkurrancer: @konkurrancer })) %>');
```

My konkurrancers controller:

```
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@Konkurrancer.id.to_s

    @theme.rating_score += params[:rating].to_i
    @theme.ratings += 1
    @theme.save

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: You'r error message does not match the code in your example. In your error message id is set as id: vind.id and in your example code is is set as id: konkurrancer.id. Please clarify.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The id is set to vind.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `vind` is not defined in your partial and you aren't passing it as a local variable either. To fix this you'll want to change `rate.js` to pass `vind` as the local variable instead of `konkurrancer`:

```
$('#<%= @container %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'rating', locals: { vind: @konkurrancer })) %>');
```

and in your konkurrancer partial:

```
<%= render 'rating', :remote => true, locals: { vind: vind } %>
```

You can then leave your ratings partial as it is with `id: vind.id`.

Comment: I still get the error. How should I render rating. I now how the following code: <%= render 'rating', :remote => true %>

Comment: I missed that use of it, but it works the same way as the other partial render call. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I used <%= render :partial => "rating", :remote => true, :locals => { :vind => vind } %> instead

Comment: That's a different error. You should create a new question for that error and you should include the relevant parts of your routes.rb file in the question. It's a different question though because it's a routing error - it seems as though you haven't properly defined some routes.

Comment: I solved the routing error. Now I get the error undefined local variable or method `f' http://pastie.org/1747846

Comment: You're missing a 'do |f|' at the end of the form, or you need to simply reformat your form and use form_for in your partial rather than form_tag. Either way, if it's a different error, like this one, please create a new question with the relevant code. I would recommend opening a new question rather than trying to resolve all the new errors that come up in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3.1 and higher version, you can check the [letsrate gem](http://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate)