# Rails help how to create rating controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a simple rating controller based on this answer.
[Rails 3 rateable model - How to create ajax rating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033879/rails-3-rateable-model-how-to-create-ajax-rating)

In my table I have:

```
rating_score => The current score
ratings => The number of ratings which led to the score
```

Here is my rate action:

```
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@konkurrancer.id.to_s

    @konkurrancer.rating_score += params[:rating].to_i
    @konkurrancer.ratings += 1
    @konkurrancer.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My log:

```
Started POST "/konkurrancers/rate/38" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-03 19:28:13 +0200

  Processing by KonkurrancersController#rate as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"q+CkUReuh0mmkSjRcd+U/JmB1tV
FWHRpOeIFxy20afs=", "vind"=>{"rating"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Gem Vind", "id"=>"38"}
  ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
ancers`
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`←
[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`cached_slug` = '38') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (15.6ms)←[0m  SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.slugga
ble_type = 'Konkurrancer' AND slugs.name = '38' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 38) LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSlug Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slug
s`.sluggable_id = 38 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Konkurrancer') ORDER BY id DE
SC LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mAREL (0.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE `konkurrancers` SET `ratings` = 84, `updated
_at` = '2011-04-03 17:28:13' WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 38)
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
Rendered konkurrancers/_rating.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered konkurrancers/rate.js.erb (31.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 250ms (Views: 171.6ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

The problem is that the param rating not gets saved.

Comment: Which of this lines has number 19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the last SQL line displayed, you'll see that it's selecting all of the ratings from your ratings table.  That makes me think that `@konkurrancer.ratings` is actually an array (a collection of ratings), and you're trying to add 1 to it when you do `@koncurrencer.ratings += 1`.  That says this is probably a class design issue.  Did you mean to have a Koncurrencer object that has many ratings objects, or did you mean for the ratings to simply be an integer sum (as it appears to be in the post that you referenced)?

Comment: How do I create a action that takes the param rating and add it to rating_score and add 1 to ratings

Comment: This is a design problem with your classes.  My guess, without seeing the rest of your code, is that you have set it up so that a Koncurrencer has_many ratings, and these ratings go live in a ratings table, when you really just want ratings to be an attribute with an accessor.  You'll need to fix the Koncurrencer class, and then your rate action will work correctly.  Alternatively, if you want the ratings to live in a separate table, then you don't need to count the number of ratings explicitly in your class, you'd just count the number of rows in the ratings table for that Koncerrencer object

Comment: I have removed the relation. Now the form submits without any errors. But the problem is that rating_score does not get submitted. The param rating is send to the action.

Comment: You should be able to look at your log file and see exactly what is getting sent to the database in the Update query.  Are you sure that your underlying database model is still correct?  Just because you removed the relationship doesn't undo the structure of your database.

Comment: It's not helpful to edit your original post once you've solved one problem and then post another, since it makes anyone else unable to learn from your question.  :)  Can you post the create_table for your koncurrencer table from your schema.rb file?

Comment: I have posted my database migration.